# Clearing Notification from invoked Activity

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I use this code to show a notification:

```
public static void ShowCustomNotification(Context context,String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage)
{

     Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        // intent triggered, you can add other intent for other actions
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ResultActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", notificationTitle);
        intent.putExtra("body", notificationMessage);
        intent.setFlags(PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.office_girl)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .build();


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification); 
}
```

When the user clicks the Notification the activity ResultActivity.class is invoked and everything is fine.

My question is how can i clear the notification on the status bar when a user click on a "Close" button from inside ResultActivity? in case the user click "Back" i dont want to clear the notification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.cancel(YOUR_NOTIFICATION_ID);
```